# Get PhoneNumber for a Contact Android 1.5

Tags: android, sqlite, contacts

For a given list of People._IDs how can I get the contacts phone number?

```
private void getCntctList(List<GroupMembers> mids){
    ArrayList<ContactItem> contact_list = new ArrayList<ContactItem>();
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    String where = "People._ID IN (";
    for (GroupMembers g : mids) {
        where += g.personId + ",";
    }
    where = where.substring(0,where.length()-1) + ")";
    Cursor contactCur = cr.query(????, null, where, null, null);
    if (contactCur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (contactCur.moveToNext()) {

            ...

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want just the primary phone number or all phone numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want the primary phone number from the contact? Your code is wrong. It should be something like this:

```
String where = Phones.PERSON_ID + " IN (";
for (GroupMembers g : mids) {
   where += g.personId + ",";
}
where += ") AND " + Phones.ISPRIMARY + " <> 0";
Cursor c = cr.query(Phones.CONTENT_URI, null, where, null, null);
if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
     do {
          // .....
     } while (c.moveToNext());
}
```

Comment: If I could hug you I would.  If I could just see a graphical depiction of these dang DB schemas I'd be money ahead.  Thanks Nic.